# Best performance for cleaning table

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have two tables with millions of rows in which an average of 300 or more rows are added every day between the two tables.
Many of these rows are rows that do not provide any information and I need to delete them.
This has been going on for over a year.
My intention is to make an algorithm that deletes from the beginning of the table and from the end, so I am eliminating the most recent entries but I am also cleaning the database from the beginning.
The problem is when doing the `SELECT` it returns an exception due to the amount of data it has to return (about 4 million).

This is the select:

```
SELECT m.id, mb.m_id, mb.id 
FROM mngm.management m
INNER JOIN managements.mngm_bkng mb ON m.id = mb.m_id
WHERE m.ma_type_id = 203 AND m.creation_date < now() - interval '24h'  LIMIT 500
```

Is there a way to select the first thousand rows and the last thousand rows keeping in mind that it has to search for all items with `m.ma_type_id = 203` and the date is getting all the results except those of the current day?

Comment: Do you have an index on `management (ma_type_id, creation_date)` ? Note that `limit` without an order by returns basically a random number of rows.

Comment: The most efficient way to get rid of old data is to partition the table (e.g. by month), then drop the partitions no longer needed. The only drawback is, that you can't have a proper primary key and thus no proper foreign key any more. Btw: 4 million rows is a rather small table these days. If properly indexed the queries should be quite faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The values are not indexed, I also think that this will not change the result much, since the date of the returned values must also be taken into account (this was not in the question, but I have already added it). I think my best option is to reduce the date range and get results and change the date ranges dynamically after each cleaning.

Comment: Well, if you don't have any indexes, this is going to be slower the more rows you have. Properly indexing your tables **is** the way to improve the performance

Comment: But index the creation date of all rows not is like do nothing?

Comment: "*But index the creation date of all rows not is like do nothing*" - No, it is **not** the same as doing nothing. Without an index, all of the rows are stored in a linear data structure, sorted *randomly*. With an index, all of the rows are stored sorted by the fields you specify (e.g. `creation_date`) already, in a logarithmic data structure with `O(log2(n))` search time, which is exponentially faster.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. Then I will do that.